How to force an OnGesture event trigger before OnClick event?
I have a Delphi (Alexandria) mobile application that takes pictures using a TCamera. These images are stored in a sqlite database. The applicacion displays a TImage and when the user clicks on it, the camera is activated and the image displays pictures continuously until it is clicked again. When that happens the picture is saved in a blob field in the database and the camera is deactivated. Everything runs fine: (Some code omitted to emphasize the essential)
procedure TfrmMain.imgBufferClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 inherited;
 // if it is active, store and deactivate
 If (camMain.Active) Then Begin
   camMain.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgBuffer.Bitmap,True);
   // code to store
   StopCam ()
   End
 // else, activate
 Else
   StartCam ()
end;

Now, due to new requirements, users want to scroll across the stored images, and also want to keep the click functionality. A gesture seemed the natural way, so I added a TGestureManager to the image, enabled the appropriates gestures and wrote a OnGesture event handler:
procedure TfrmMain.imgBufferGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);

begin
 inherited;
 With tableWithImages Do
   Case EventInfo.GestureID Of
     sgiLeft            : Prior;
     sgiRight           : Next;
     sgiSemiCircleLeft  : First;
     sgiSemiCircleRight : Last
     End;

 UpdateScreen (1);      // loads the picture and other information on the app
 Handled := True
end;

Here's the problem: I'm a Android newbie and don't know if this standard behavior but after the OnGesture triggers, also a OnClick does (Later I found that is backwards) My initial guess was that OnGesture was an isolated event, so I added a flag like:
procedure TfrmMain.imgBufferGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);

begin
 inherited;
 With tableWithImages Do
   Case EventInfo.GestureID Of
     sgiLeft            : Prior;
     sgiRight           : Next;
     sgiSemiCircleLeft  : First;
     sgiSemiCircleRight : Last
     End;

 UpdateScreen (1);      // loads the picture and other information on the app
 Handled := True;
 FLAG_TO_INDICATE_GESTURE := True // global property
end;

procedure TfrmMain.imgBufferClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 inherited;
 If (FLAG_TO_INDICATE_GESTURE) Then Begin
   FLAG_TO_INDICATE_GESTURE := False;
   Exit
   End;

 // if it is active, store and deactivate
 If (camMain.Active) Then Begin
   camMain.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgBuffer.Bitmap,True);
   // code to store
   StopCam ()
   End
 // else, activate
 Else
   StartCam ()
end;

To further complicate matters, OnClick is triggered BEFORE OnGesture and so, FLAG_TO_INDICATE_GESTURE is useless.
So, how can I force OnGesture to trigger before OnClick or not trigger at all when the user does a gesture? I want the application to behave like this:

If the user does a gesture, respond to it but not trigger OnClick
If the user clicks the image, respond as usual


As far as I know you can also detect click using gesture.  If my memory serves me correctly the GestureID for simple click would be sgiNoGesture.
